# Change the color of a line in flot.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I have a line graph with data for each month. No matter where I add the color option in the option list or even as part of the data the line is still the default yellow.

Here is the code that has it working with the default.

Where do i need to add a color variable to make it display.

```
  var plotData = [[1, data.data['Jan']], [2, data.data['Feb']], [3, data.data['Mar']], [4, data.data['Apr']], [5, data.data['May']], [6, data.data['June']], [7, data.data['July']], [8, data.data['Aug']], [9, data.data['Sep']], [10, data.data['Oct']], [11, data.data['Nov']], [12, data.data['Dec']]];

                                $.plot('#placeholder', [plotData]), {

                                    series: {
                                        lines: {
                                            show: true,
                                            lineWidth: 4,

                                        },
                                        points: {
                                            show: true
                                        },
                                        shadowSize: 0

                                    },
                                    grid: {
                                        hoverable: true,
                                        clickable: false,
                                        borderColor: '#EDEDED',
                                        borderWidth: 1,
                                        labelMargin: 15,
                                        backgroundColor: '#FFF'
                                    },
                                    yaxis: {
                                        min: 0,
                                        color: '#EDEDED'
                                    },
                                    xaxis: {
                                        color: '#FFF',

                                    },
                                    legend: {
                                        show: false
                                    },
                                    tooltip: true,
                                    tooltipOpts: {
                                        content: '%x: %y',
                                        shifts: {
                                            x: -30,
                                            y: 25
                                        },
                                        defaultTheme: false
                                    }

                                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `)` from behind `[plotdata]` to the end of the options object:

```
$.plot('#placeholder', [plotData]), {
                                 ^
```

As it is now, you call plot without options, so the default options are used.
Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0mpafq59/) which shows the working code.

For the right way to define custom colors, see [here](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-data-series) or in the above fiddle.

Comment: Well, this would explain a lot! Will mark as correct when I get a chance to try it.